# Cannot add MSSQL .mdf file in VS2017 project on my local system

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

I'm pretty new here, so this is my first question.

I am currently working on a project in Visual Studio 2017.
It is an application that shows some data from a local database, in the MSSQL lanuage. 
When trying to add a *.mdf file through the Solution Explorer, i get the following error:

"A network-related or instance-specific error occured while establishinh a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error:50 - Local Database Runtime Error occured. Unexpected error occured inside a LocalDB instance API method call. See the Windows Application event log for details.)"

The SQLSERVER-process is active and running, according to my TaskManager and in the Server Explorer, I am able to add a new database.

I've tried to reinstall both Visual Studio 2017 and SQL Server Express 2016, but this didn't solve the problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Instead of a link to some site that nobody has ever heard of can you post the error message here?

Comment: @SeanLange I've eddited the question, sorry for the inconvenience